# td style in repeater won't output bound value ("This is not a scriptlet. Will output as plain text")

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a repeater with a table in it with lots of properties of the td's bound by the repeater.
I have had to add a runat server to each td so I can add a visible attribute, because depending on the data some tds aren't visible.

Now I have added the runat server I am having a problem setting the background colour of my tds. It is done with a bound value.
When I add my <%%> tags to my style they are output as plain text, It even says in my html that "This is not a scriptlet. Will output as plain text"  where as the rest of my <%%> tags bind correctly.

Why won't my style bind anymore?

Other tags I add will, but just not style?

Here's a cut down version of my repeater.

```
   <table id="Table1" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="groups">
                <tr id="Tr1" class="thead">

                    <td colspan='<%#AllowedItems.Count() %>' align="center">
                        items
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="theadL">
                    <td id="Td1" runat="server" visible='<%#ItemAllowed("Item1")%>'>
                        item1
                    </td>
                    <td id="Td2" runat="server" visible='<%#ItemAllowed("Item2")%>'>
                       item2
                    </td>
                    <td id="Td3" runat="server" visible='<%#ItemAllowed("Item3")%>'>
                      item 3
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# GetData((int)Eval("Id"))%>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>                                                              
                            <td id="Td9" title='<%#Eval("Item1Status")%>' runat="server" visible='<%#ItemAllowed("Item1")%>'
                                style='background-color: <%#Eval("Item1StatusColour")%>;'>
                            </td>
                            <td id="Td10" title='<%#Eval("Item2Status")%>' runat="server" visible='<%#ItemAllowed("Item3")%>'
                                style='background-color: <%#Eval("Item3StatusColour")%>;'>
                            </td>
                            <td id="Td11" title='<%#Eval("Item3Status")%>' runat="server" visible='<%#ItemAllowed("Item4")%>'
                                style='background-color: <%#Eval("Item4StatusColour")%>;'>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

**Update**

The style renders like this :

```
 style="background-color:&lt;%# &quot;&quot;+ Eval(&quot;Item1StatusColour&quot;)%>;"
```

All the rest of the attribute render how they should.

**Update**
This is the ItemAllowed method as requested

```
     public bool ItemAllowed(string item)
        {
//allowed items is a list<string>

            return AllowedItems.Contains(item);
        }
```

Comment: Can you please post your rendered HTML as well as the ASP.NET code, so we can see how this is outputting?

Comment: I have added how the style renders as this was a sample bit of code just to show the problem, the rest render as normal (other than visible, because if it's invisible it doesn't show at all)

Comment: Please post the code for your ItemAllowed function

Comment: Item Allowed just checks a list<string> on the server side to see if it contains the string. Have added above.

Comment: Should you be using `visible='<%#ItemAllowed(Eval("Item1"))%>` then? Not that this will solve your main problem I don't think...

Comment: No I am not binding a value there. I am just using the <%#%> to get at the serverside. I am only doing it there as it's more difficult making the tds invisible directly from code.

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: 2010 with what ever the latest service pack is

Comment: Have you tried using `<%= %>` instead of `<%# %>` for the `style` attribute value.  You'll need to do concatenation as suggested below:  `<td ... style='<%= "background-color:" + Eval("Item2StatusColour")%>'>`.  If this works, I'll be happy to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would recommend is using css classes instead of what you are doing.

When you use html elements with runat=server, you are converting it into an html control and .net is rendering the final output.  Your particular issue arises from .net wrapping the value with htmlencode or something to that effect.

I would suggest perhaps using a gridview with a onrowdatabound event.  Then you can do anything programmitically in the code-behind.

Comment: I still don't understand why it won't let me assign a style, but it will let me assign a class, so this is the answer.

Comment: the class is understood as a literal (no special characters).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it likes a combination of code and inline strings, so you could try doing it all in code:

```
<td ... style='<%# "background-color:" + Eval("Item2StatusColour")%>'>
```

Unfortunately don't have VS in front of me so can't verify it, let me know if it works.

Comment: thnx but this doesn't make any difference! Still renders as style="&lt;%# &quot;background-color:&quot;+ Eval(&quot;Item1StatusColour&quot;)%>;"

Comment: Strange, this seems to suggest I have the right idea: http://forums.asp.net/t/1065621.aspx/1

Comment: I really don't understand why though? It all worked fine until I added   a visible and runat server .

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that my answer is exactly the same as Sir Crispalot's! I have however tested this and I've replicated the bug and the fix in Visual Studio 2008...

Like this...

```
<td id="Td9" title='<%#Eval("Item1Status")%>' 
    runat="server" 
    visible='<%#ItemAllowed("Item2")%>'
    style='<%# "background-color:" + Eval("Item2StatusColour")%>' >
```

I believe that `Eval` is expecting a dataitem name, not an expression. However `<%# %>` expects an expression which can contain operations. The `Eval` can then be used within here and concatenated to the string `"background-color"`.

I don't fully grok all the asp inline-tags - they're always a headache!

PS - I notice there is a mismatch between the Item numbers within your `<td>`s - is this intentional? eg Item1 and Item2 are referenced within the same `<td>`...

Comment: El Ronnoco. The mis-match is just a typo (and now corrected). I tried the suggestion but it made no difference. It worked fine when no runat server though and in VS when in the HTML view if I just type style='<%%>' it will squiggle and say not a scriptlet. It doesn't seem to care what I put in it!

Comment: Item Allowed just checks a list<string> on the server side to see if it contains the string. Have added above

Answer (score 0):

If your controls are runat server I would personally recommend hooking into the `OnItemDataBound` event within the repeater, and then in your code behind handle all of your calculations there. Here's a quick example

**ASPX**

```
...
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptItems_OnItemDataBound" DataSource='<%# GetData((int)Eval("Id"))%>'>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>                                                              
            <td id="Td9" runat="server"></td>
            <td id="Td10" runat="server"></td>
            <td id="Td11" runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
...
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void rptItems_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item)
    {
        return;
    }

    var currentItem = e.Item as YourDataItemTypeHere;
    var td9 = e.Item.FindControl("Td9") as HtmlTableCell;
    td9.Attributes["title"] = currentItem.Item1Status;
    td9.Style["background-color"] = currentItem.Item2StatusColour;

    ...
}
```

**On a side note**

From a more readable perspective I would also recommend renaming controls to something more readable, i.e. what is `td9`, `td10` and `td11`? Instead it would be easier to understand if it were say `tdFirstStatus`, `tdSecondStatus` and `tdThirdStatus`, but that's just a preference thing.

Comment: I have renamed them now and I am using item databound. What I want t know is why it doesn't work